# How to export/download my Amazon wishlist?

Tags: amazon, export

How can I export/download my Amazon wishlist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/17278

> Script Summary: Adds 2 buttons to the Amazon Wishlist page: 1 for a printable version of the page, and another for CSV export.

Here's how to [install userscripts](https://superuser.com/q/252046/4377).

Comment: Please make it a point to expand the answers instead of just a link

Comment: doesn't work for me with Tampermonkey and Chrome Version 72.0.3626.119 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

This userscript from 2016 still works:

https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/19871-amazon-wishlist-export

1. Install a userscripts add-on for your browser (Firefox, Chrome), e.g. Greasemonkey, [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/), Greasefork etc.
2. Then install above mentioned script, visit your Amazon wishlist and click newly added "Export wishlist" button to receive your wishlist as JSON.