# Exporting and Importing various Amazon lists; Shopping Lists, Wish lists, Idea Lists, Default List?

Tags: amazon, export, import

This question circa 2011: [How to export/download my Amazon wishlist?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18347/how-to-export-download-my-amazon-wishlist)

- Now, we have multiple lists in addition to the default wish list, that we make and change various times.
- At times we wish to export and import them from one Amazon profile (of family/ friends) to another.
- At times export/import only a full or partial list.

Basically some list management across profiles and being able to save/keep versions of it over time.

**Update:**

Note:

- I am not talking about list sharing via URL/ Email that amazon already has. I wish to be able to export/ download offline copies of chosen Lists (even better if I can choose "selected items" from the list), change/ edit as I want and then be able to import them to where I want. Please point me to an extension that do such a thing?
- So thats at least 2 features so far, lets go for a bit more detail:

  1. Offline editing -- what are you editing in the offline copy? Are you adding new items and removing some?
  2. Import where you want, meaning to another account as owned list? I'm not aware of extension that would do this, I merely said that its pretty straight forward to make.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Creating an extension that allows list sharing is pretty trivial, but I'm not convinced theres a big need.

Comment: @fixanoid - I am not talking about list sharing via URL/ Email that amazon already has. I wish to be able to export/ download offline copies of chosen Lists (even better if I can choose "selected items" from the list), change/ edit as I want and then be able to import them to where I want. Please point me to an extension that do such a thing?

Comment: So thats at least 2 features so far, lets go for a bit more detail:
1. Offline editing -- what are you editing in the offline copy? Are you adding new items and removing some?
2. Import where you want, meaning to another account as owned list? 

I'm not aware of extension that would do this, I merely said that its pretty straight forward to make.